# Expectation of product of two random variables conditional on a linear combination

Tags: probability

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction for this probability problem.

Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be continuous random variables with unit variances and such that,

$E( X ) \ne 0$
$E( Y ) = 0 $
$E( Z ) = 0 $
$E( XY ) = 0$
$E( XZ ) = 0$
$E( YZ ) = \rho$.

That is, $Y$ and $Z$ are correlated, but $X$ is uncorrelated with both $Y$ and $Z$ (if need be I'm willing to assume all r.v.'s are jointly normal.)

The object I wish to characterize is:

$ W = Cov( XY | Z + \lambda_1 X > \lambda_0 ), $

where the $\lambda$ are finite constants.  Clearly $W=0$ if $\rho=0$ and $\lambda_1=0$, and I think that if $\lambda_1=0$ then it's also zero regardless of $\rho$, but I'm having trouble proving it.  I also think that the magnitude of $W$ is increasing in both (the magnitude of) $\rho$ and $\lambda_1$, but again I'm trouble proving it.

Thanks for any help and/or pointers.  Chris.